# Browser tab information for image created by servlet

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I'm using a servlet to show images on page. The links looks like

```
http://webappname.com/getImage?p=imagename.jpg
```

But the resulting image *in the browser **tab*** shows

> getImage (100x200)

I would like to output there more useful information like string, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the response is an image, it cannot contain additional information (such as the page title) as an HTML response could.  One possible workaround to this would be to return a simple HMTL page with your image in it.

You could trigger then trigger the regular download (the existing behaviour) with an additional URL parameter.  So for example:

```
http://webappname.com/getImage?p=imagename.jpg
```

Would return this HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="img-dl-style.css">
    <script type="application/javascript">
      // JavaScript to trigger image download when #dlButton is clicked
    </script>
    <title>Full Image Name</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Full Image Name</h1>
      <img src="http://webappname.com/getImage?p=imagename.jpg&dl=1>
      <button id="dlButton" type="button">Download this image</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any direct access to this URL:

```
http://webappname.com/getImage?p=imagename.jpg&dl=1
```

Would return the image directly, complete with the default browser title.

---

To see this in action, take a look at Dropbox's shared file viewer.  A link such as:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmocfrco2t0d28o/Fluffbeast.docx
```

Returns a full webpage with a preview of the shared file and a download button.  Clicking the button triggers the download with this URL:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmocfrco2t0d28o/Fluffbeast.docx?dl=1
```